# ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function

Tags: python

I have a class assignment to write a python program to download end-of-day data last 25 years the major global stock market indices from Yahoo Finance:

- Dow Jones Index (USA)
- S&P 500 (USA)
- NASDAQ (USA)
- DAX (Germany)
- FTSE (UK)
- HANGSENG (Hong Kong)
- KOSPI (Korea)
- CNX NIFTY (India)

Unfortunately, when I run the program an error occurs.

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\yahoofinancials__init__.py", line 91, in format_date
>       form_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(in_date)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
>
> ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function

If you see below, you can see the code that I have written. I'm trying to debug my mistakes. Can you help me out please? Thanks

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import pandas as pd

# Select Tickers and stock history dates
index1 = '^DJI'
index2 = '^GSPC'
index3 = '^IXIC'
index4 = '^GDAXI'
index5 = '^FTSE'
index6 = '^HSI'
index7 = '^KS11'
index8 = '^NSEI'
freq = 'daily'
start_date = '1993-06-30'
end_date = '2018-06-30'


# Function to clean data extracts
def clean_stock_data(stock_data_list):
    new_list = []
    for rec in stock_data_list:
        if 'type' not in rec.keys():
            new_list.append(rec)
    return new_list

# Construct yahoo financials objects for data extraction
dji_financials = YahooFinancials(index1)
gspc_financials = YahooFinancials(index2)
ixic_financials = YahooFinancials(index3)
gdaxi_financials = YahooFinancials(index4)
ftse_financials = YahooFinancials(index5)
hsi_financials = YahooFinancials(index6)
ks11_financials = YahooFinancials(index7)
nsei_financials = YahooFinancials(index8)


# Clean returned stock history data and remove dividend events from price history
daily_dji_data = clean_stock_data(dji_financials
                                     .get_historical_stock_data(start_date, end_date, freq)[index1]['prices'])
daily_gspc_data = clean_stock_data(gspc_financials
                                     .get_historical_stock_data(start_date, end_date, freq)[index2]['prices'])
daily_ixic_data = clean_stock_data(ixic_financials
                                     .get_historical_stock_data(start_date, end_date, freq)[index3]['prices'])
daily_gdaxi_data = clean_stock_data(gdaxi_financials
                                     .get_historical_stock_data(start_date, end_date, freq)[index4]['prices'])                                   
daily_ftse_data = clean_stock_data(ftse_financials
                                     .get_historical_stock_data(start_date, end_date, freq)[index5]['prices'])                         
daily_hsi_data = clean_stock_data(hsi_financials
                                     .get_historical_stock_data(start_date, end_date, freq)[index6]['prices'])
daily_ks11_data = clean_stock_data(ks11_financials
                                     .get_historical_stock_data(start_date, end_date, freq)[index7]['prices'])
daily_nsei_data = clean_stock_data(nsei_financials
                                     .get_historical_stock_data(start_date, end_date, freq)[index8]['prices'])
stock_hist_data_list = [{'^DJI': daily_dji_data}, {'^GSPC': daily_gspc_data}, {'^IXIC': daily_ixic_data},
                        {'^GDAXI': daily_gdaxi_data}, {'^FTSE': daily_ftse_data}, {'^HSI': daily_hsi_data},
                        {'^KS11': daily_ks11_data}, {'^NSEI': daily_nsei_data}]


# Function to construct data frame based on a stock and it's market index
def build_data_frame(data_list1, data_list2, data_list3, data_list4, data_list5, data_list6, data_list7, data_list8):
    data_dict = {}
    i = 0
    for list_item in data_list2:
        if 'type' not in list_item.keys():
            data_dict.update({list_item['formatted_date']: {'^DJI': data_list1[i]['close'], '^GSPC': list_item['close'],
                                                            '^IXIC': data_list3[i]['close'], '^GDAXI': data_list4[i]['close'],
                                                            '^FTSE': data_list5[i]['close'], '^HSI': data_list6[i]['close'],     
                                                            '^KS11': data_list7[i]['close'], '^NSEI': data_list8[i]['close']}})
            i += 1
    tseries = pd.to_datetime(list(data_dict.keys()))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(data_dict.values()), index=tseries,
                      columns=['^DJI', '^GSPC', '^IXIC', '^GDAXI', '^FTSE', '^HSI', '^KS11', '^NSEI']).sort_index()
    return df
```

Comment: `date.fromtimestamp` classmethod restricted to years from 1970 through 2038. I guess you have a timestamp in your data that is out of this range. If you can edit the file that error occurred, you can choose `timedelta` for more range to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your datetime stamps are in the wrong format.  If you look at the error code it clugely tells you:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(in_date)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Notice the `int(in_date)` part?

It wants the unix timestamp. There are several ways to get this, out of the time module or the calendar module, or using Arrow.

```
import datetime
import calendar

date = datetime.datetime.strptime("1993-06-30", "%Y-%m-%d")
start_date = calendar.timegm(date.utctimetuple())
```

*** UPDATED ***
OK so I fixed up to the dataframes portion.  Here is my current code:

```
# Select Tickers and stock history dates
index = {'DJI' : YahooFinancials('^DJI'),
         'GSPC' : YahooFinancials('^GSPC'),
         'IXIC':YahooFinancials('^IXIC'),
         'GDAXI':YahooFinancials('^GDAXI'),
         'FTSE':YahooFinancials('^FTSE'),
         'HSI':YahooFinancials('^HSI'),
         'KS11':YahooFinancials('^KS11'),
         'NSEI':YahooFinancials('^NSEI')}
freq = 'daily'
start_date = '1993-06-30'
end_date = '2018-06-30'

# Clean returned stock history data and remove dividend events from price history
daily = {}
for k in index:
    tmp = index[k].get_historical_stock_data(start_date, end_date, freq)
    if tmp:
        daily[k] = tmp['^{}'.format(k)]['prices'] if 'prices' in tmp['^{}'.format(k)] else []
```

Unfortunately I had to fix a couple things in the yahoo module.  For the class YahooFinanceETL:

```
@staticmethod
def format_date(in_date, convert_type):
    try:
        x = int(in_date)
        convert_type = 'standard'
    except:
        convert_type = 'unixstamp'
    if convert_type == 'standard':
        if in_date < 0:
            form_date = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=in_date)
        else:
            form_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(in_date)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    else:
        split_date = in_date.split('-')
        d = date(int(split_date[0]), int(split_date[1]), int(split_date[2]))
        form_date = int(time.mktime(d.timetuple()))
    return form_date
```

AND:

```
   # private static method to scrap data from yahoo finance
    @staticmethod
    def _scrape_data(url, tech_type, statement_type):
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        script = soup.find("script", text=re.compile("root.App.main")).text
        data = loads(re.search("root.App.main\s+=\s+(\{.*\})", script).group(1))
        if tech_type == '' and statement_type != 'history':
            stores = data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["QuoteSummaryStore"]
        elif tech_type != '' and statement_type != 'history':
            stores = data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["QuoteSummaryStore"][tech_type]
        else:
            if "HistoricalPriceStore" in data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"] :
                stores = data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
            else:
                stores = data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["QuoteSummaryStore"]
        return stores
```

You will want to look at the `daily` dict, and rewrite your `build_data_frame` function, which it should be a lot simpler now since you are working with a dictionary already.

Comment: How do I code the start date and end date? Can I code like this?

from datetime import date, timedelta

start_date = date(1993, 6, 30) # start date
end_date = date(2018, 6, 30) # end date

delta = end_date - start_date # timedelta

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    print(start_date + timedelta(i))

Comment: Thanks, the date works. Now, I receive another error. 

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoofinancials\__init__.py", line 93, in format_date
    split_date = in_date.split('-')

AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Ok that is actually not working then... let me get into the software a bit and see what's happening

Comment: After reviewing the code for the yahoofinancials, it is totally broken.  The reason your script is breaking isn't your fault.  For some reason this module is sending the wrong time with the wrong flag value.  I fixed the function (to be right all the time) and fixed the negative epoch issue it was having.  And it is still broken.  `line 130, in _scrape_data
    stores = data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
KeyError: 'HistoricalPriceStore'`

Comment: OK, Thank you eatmeimadanish. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I updated my solution with some fixes.  I had to change functions inside the yahoo financials module.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually the maintainer and author of YahooFinancials. I just saw this post and wanted to personally apologize for the inconvenience and let you all know I will be working on fixing the module this evening.

Could you please open an issue on the module's Github page detailing this?
It would also be very helpful to know which version of python you were running when you encountered these issues.
https://github.com/JECSand/yahoofinancials/issues

I am at work right now, however as soon as I get home in ~7 hours or so I will attempt to code a fix and release it. I'll also work on the exception handling. I try my best to maintain this module, but my day (and often night time) job is rather demanding. I will report back with the final results of these fixes and publish to pypi when it is done and stable.

Also if anyone else has any feedback or personal fixes made you can offer, it would be a huge huge help in fixing this. Proper credit will be given of course. I am also in desperate need of contributers, so if anyone is interested in that as well let me know. I am really wanting to take YahooFinancials to the next level and have this project become a stable and reliable alternative for free financial data for python projects.

Thank you for your patience and for using YahooFinancials.

Comment: Hi alt777, I was using YahooFinancials V0.4. I will post the issue in https://github.com/JECSand/yahoofinancials/issues

Comment: Hi Johannes,

I looked into the error:
line 130, in _scrape_data stores = data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"] KeyError: 'HistoricalPriceStore'

When I tried to replicate I only got that error for FTSE. I investigated and realized that the Historical Data table my code hashes the data out of for stock price data does not exists for FTSE. The only way I can think of to get that data would be through the interactive chart. I have been unable to find a datastore there thus far. I am however building in try except handlers to return tickers without data with a null.

Comment: To demonstrate the missing stock data table for FTSE i was talking about:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^DJI/history?period1=741416400&period2=1530334800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

vs

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^FTSE/history?period1=741416400&period2=1530334800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

The place with the data is:
https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/^FTSE

I just haven't found a way to get to it yet. This next release I am putting up tonight will have the error handlers to make this smoother until I can find a way to get that data w/o a web driver.